Настройка получения testcontainers/ryuk из внутренних ресурсов
Использую testcontainers для юнит и интеграционных тестов на java. Мне нужно их запускать на стенде во внутренней сети. Но проблема в том, что сеть не имеет выхода в интернет, а может пользоваться только внутренними ресурсами. При этом для работы testcontainers требуется образ testcontainers/ryuk. Как можно настроить testcontainers так, чтобы указать ему, откуда загрузить testcontainers/ryuk?
